# How to get the k8s ingress wildcard in the host and put it on the url path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I use k8s to deploy my services.
I hope when I access the ingress host **foo.example.com** and the ingress forward it to **server:8000/proxy/foo**. The subdomain **foo** is dynamic and can be changed to any word. The expected result is as below:

- foo.example.com -> server:8000/proxy/foo
- bar.example.com -> server:8000/proxy/bar
- ......

I knew the ingress host could use wildcards and use ingress-nginx [rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) can rewrite the url path. I use the ingress-nginx controller. The ingress yaml file like as below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /proxy/${wildcard}/$1 # Could I use the host wildcard here?
name: nginx-forward
spec:
  rules:
  - host: *.example.com # I want to get the subdomain wildcard
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        service:
          name: service
        port:
          number: 8080
      path: /(.*)
      pathType: Prefix
  tls: # update this attribute
  - hosts:
    - *.example.com 
    secretName: my-secret
```

How could I use k8s ingress or other things to get what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use server snippet to get the subdomain:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      server_name     ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /proxy/$subdomain/$1 
name: nginx-forward
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        service:
          name: service
        port:
          number: 8080
      path: /(.*)
      pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: I try your ingress yaml and it reports the "unknown subdomain variable" error.

Comment: Is it the error reason I have the "tls" attribute in yaml? and it reports the error? But I try to remove the "tls" part and it reports the same error. I have updated the yaml in the source question.

Comment: Sorry there was an "s" at the end of the server-snippet annotation. I removed it.

Comment: That is work! And I found I can use http-snippets can do the same thing.  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/http-snippets: |
       map $http_host $sudomain {
         ~(?<subdomain>\\w+)\\.example\\.com $sudomain;
         default '';
       }

Comment: Another thing I found is when I use server-snippet the spec.rules[0].host can be set to "*.example.com" and work fine too.

Comment: I'm glad it works. You can do lots of things with all the snippet annotations :)

Comment: Regarding "*.example.com" in the rule, this will just add another server_name line in the server section of the generated nginx.conf. But the one that effectively matches is the one from the server snippet.